# APP SUPPOURT IPV6 Api

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes-store, appledoc

I am using NsUrl Session throughout whole app. Is their any need for change of API. WILL  apple approved my APP.My api http://alatiffy.com/webservice/terms.php

Comment: test it........

Comment: How i will test ?.

Comment: India not suppourt iPV6

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=apple+ios+test+ipv6

Comment: @Wain i am creating local ipV6. It show on my phone but not connected. Can is their any another . Please help...

Comment: @Wain Please will you check this api work on ipV6 only.